# MySQL Trigger Syntax ? Whats wrong with this one?

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

Hi all Im trying to recreate a trigger
I did a show create trigger and copied the original sql ;
Now when i run it i get an syntax error. ?? Any Idead

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER    `update_cached_tables_for_product_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `Product` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO ProductOffercount (product_id, num_offers) VALUES (NEW.id, 0); END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql treats `;` after your query (that is the part of trigger definition) as the end of the whole statement. Thus you get syntax error.

You need to redefine delimiter before `CREATE TRIGGER` clause:

```
delimiter |

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `update_cached_tables_for_product_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `Product`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        INSERT INTO ProductOffercount (product_id, num_offers) VALUES (NEW.id, 0);

    END;
|

delimiter ;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html